# Superset Postgres The port is closed

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, driver, wsl-2, apache-superset

I have installed Superset from the Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows app. And I have installed postgres directly in windows laptop.

When I try to connect to postgres, It gives 'The port is closed' error (see first screenshot).

I have spent an entire day searching for the fix, but haven't found any fix. Hence posting my question here. I would really appreciate if someone could help me fix this issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A network configuration or firewall problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should install and start your postgres in Ubuntu environment too.
If not, superset which is running in Ubuntu cannot listen to postgres port.

Answer (score 0):

If you are use superset using docker image,

Solution : Instead of using "localhost" use **host.docker.internal**

If you are use ubuntu env it is environment problem because your localhost on windows and superset on ubuntu environment.